# click on right of screen come 1st after last slide/click on left of screen in come 1st after 2nd slide

Tags: jquery

When I click on current slide (first) on right side of screen, slide right to left and shows second slide and 3rd, 4th, 5th slide well, But on next click (5th time), don't show 1st slide and there is blank screen. Also when I click on current slide (first) on left side of screen, slide left to right and shows 5th slide and 4th, 3rd, 2nd slide well, But on next click (5th time), don't show 1st slide and there is blank screen. Slide number works well on click of both left and right side of screen. I given below html structure and jquery. Can anyone improve this to solve this issue. Thanks in advance.

HTML

```
<div class="home-slide">
    <div class="slide-wrapper">
        <div class="slide">slide 1</div>
        <div class="slide">slide 2</div>
        <div class="slide">slide 3</div>
        <div class="slide">slide 4</div>
        <div class="slide">slide 5</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="slide-number">
    <div class="active">1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.slide-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: #fff;
}
.slide {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    padding: 100px 40px;
    clip: rect(0 1366px 660px 0);
    -webkit-transition: linear .5s;
    transition: linear .5s;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
}
.slide:nth-child(1) {
    background-color: #F2358D;
    /*--magenta shade--*/
    z-index: 5;
}
.slide:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: #04D9B2;
    /*--cyne shade--*/
    z-index: 4;
}
.slide:nth-child(3) {
    background-color: #F2C53D;
    /*--yellow shade--*/
    z-index: 3;
}
.slide:nth-child(4) {
    background-color: #6a8aff;
    /*--blue shade--*/
    z-index: 2;
}
.slide:nth-child(5) {
    background-color: #3FFF42;
    /*--green shade--*/
    z-index: 1;
}
.slide-clip-left {
    clip: rect(0 1365px 660px 1365px);
}
.slide-clip-right{
    clip: rect(0 0 1365px 0);
}

.slide-number {
    display: flex;
    max-width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 45%;
    transform-x: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 999;
}

.slide-number div {
    padding: 20px 10px;
    opacity: .5;
}
.slide-number div.active {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

jquery

```
var $numbers = $('.slide-number').children();
var $slides = $('.slide');
var numSlides = $slides.length;
var currentSlideL = 0;
var currentSlideR = 0;

$('.slide').click(function(e) {
    var pWidth = $(this).innerWidth(); //use .outerWidth() if you want borders
    var pOffset = $(this).offset(); 
    var x = e.pageX - pOffset.left;

    if(pWidth/2 > x){
        currentSlideL = (currentSlideL - 1) % numSlides;
        var $targetL = $slides.eq(currentSlideL);
        setTimeout(() => {
            $(this).addClass('slide-clip-left').animate({'z-index': 1 });
            $numbers.eq(currentSlideL).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
        }, 500);
        $target.removeClass('slide-clip-left').delay(200).animate({'z-index': 5 });
    }
    else if(pWidth/2 < x) {
        currentSlideR = (currentSlideR + 1) % numSlides;
        var $targetR = $slides.eq(currentSlideR);
        setTimeout(() => {
            $(this).addClass('slide-clip-right').animate({'z-index': 1 });
            $numbers.eq(currentSlideR).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
        }, 500);
        $target.removeClass('slide-clip-right').delay(200).animate({'z-index': 5 });
    }
});
```

I expect slider work well when I click on right side of screen, 1st slide should show and when click on left side of screen, 1st slide shows after second slide.

Comment: post your CSS , and in your code $target is not defined

Comment: @Sim1-81, Thanks for your reply. I set $target as $targetL and $targetR respectively and it works. But another issue is created, When I click continues on anyone side of screen, it's ok but in between I click opposite side of that, slide don't  show and screen get blank. can you help me what's going wrong. Please check css as I updated.

Comment: Below the solution, but with some manipulation of your code, i hope this can helps you

Answer (score 0):

OK i got the solution, but i have changed the approach.
here the new code. I also added some responsiveness to slider. Now instead of z-index, i check the margin-left to animate the slider container and not only 1 slide at time, so i don't have to know whitch is te current slide to find the next one, i just care about if margin is less than 0 and more than the difference between the `.slide` width and the `.slider-wrapper` width. In this way when you click on the left i subtract to the margin-left the current `.slide` width and add it when right is clicked. Take a look at `resize_slider()` function. Last thing but not for relevance putting `.stop()` before `.animate()` prevents overlapping of animations.
P.S. you can use the same approach to animate with CSS transform

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>


        <style>
            body{ margin: 0; padding:0}
            .home-slide{
                overflow: hidden;
                width: 100%;
            }
            .slide-wrapper {
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: row;
                overflow: hidden;
                width: 100%;
                height: 80vh;
                color: #fff;
               
            }
            .slide {
                position: relative;
                height: 100%;
                min-height: 100%;
                padding: 100px 40px;
                
                -webkit-transition: linear .5s;
                transition: linear .5s;
                cursor: pointer;
                border: none;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                font-size: 20px
            }

            .slide:nth-child(1) {
                background-color: #F2358D;
                /*--magenta shade--*/

            }
            .slide:nth-child(2) {
                background-color: #04D9B2;
                /*--cyne shade--*/

            }
            .slide:nth-child(3) {
                background-color: #F2C53D;
                /*--yellow shade--*/

            }
            .slide:nth-child(4) {
                background-color: #6a8aff;
                /*--blue shade--*/

            }
            .slide:nth-child(5) {
                background-color: #3FFF42;
                /*--green shade--*/

            }

            .slide-number {
                display: flex;
                max-width: 100%;
                position: absolute;
                bottom: 0;
                left: 45%;
                transform-x: 50%;
                text-align: center;
                z-index: 999;
            }

            .slide-number div {
                padding: 20px 10px;
                opacity: .5;
            }
            .slide-number div.active {
                opacity: 1;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="home-slide">
            <div class="slide-wrapper">
                <div class="slide">slide 1</div>
                <div class="slide">slide 2</div>
                <div class="slide">slide 3</div>
                <div class="slide">slide 4</div>
                <div class="slide">slide 5</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slide-number">
            <div class="active">1</div>
            <div>2</div>
            <div>3</div>
            <div>4</div>
            <div>5</div>
        </div>
        
        <script>
            var $numbers,$slides,numSlides,isSliding,currSlide = 1;

            console.log('numSlides', numSlides)
            $(document).ready(function () {
                resizeSlides();

                $('.slide').click(function (e) {
                    var pWidth = $(this).outerWidth(); //use .outerWidth() if you want borders
                    var pOffset = $(this).offset();
                    var x = e.pageX - pOffset.left;
                    console.log($('.slide-wrapper').css('marginLeft'))
                    var posX = Math.floor(parseInt($('.slide-wrapper').css('marginLeft').replace('px')));
                    var sliderW = Math.floor($('.slide-wrapper').width())
                    var direction;
                    
                    if (pWidth / 2 > x) {
                        direction = 'left';

                    } else if (pWidth / 2 < x) {
                        direction = 'right';
                    }
                    
                    console.log('(pWidth - sliderW)',(pWidth - sliderW));
                    
                    console.log('posX', posX);
                    console.log('typeof posX', typeof posX);
                    console.log('pWidth', pWidth);
                    console.log('sliderW', sliderW);
                    console.log('(pWidth - sliderW)',(pWidth - sliderW));

                    if (!isSliding) {
                        isSliding = true;
                        if (direction == 'left' && posX < 0) {
                            $('.slide-wrapper').stop().animate({'marginLeft': '+=' + pWidth + 'px'}, 500, function () {
                                currSlide--;
                                $('.slide-number .active').removeClass('active')
                                $('.slide-number div:nth-child(' + (currSlide) + ')').addClass('active');
                                
isSliding = false;
                            });
                        } else if (direction == 'right' && (pWidth - sliderW) < posX) {
                            $('.slide-wrapper').stop().animate({'marginLeft': '-=' + pWidth + 'px'}, 500, function () {
                                currSlide++;
                                $('.slide-number .active').removeClass('active')
                                $('.slide-number div:nth-child(' + (currSlide) + ')').addClass('active');
                                 
isSliding = false;
                            });
                        }
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            isSliding = false;
                        }, 500)
                    }
                });

            })



            $(window).resize(function () {
                resizeSlides();
            });
            function  resizeSlides() {
                $numbers = $('.slide-number').children();
                $slides = $('.slide');
                numSlides = $slides.length;
                isSliding = false;
                currSlide = 1;
                var sliderW = Math.floor($('.home-slide').width());

                var numSlides = $('.slide-number').children().length;
                $('.slide').each(function () {
                    $(this).outerWidth(sliderW); 
                });
                $('.slide-wrapper').width(sliderW * numSlides);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Very thanks for your coding and efforts. This is well approach. But I am trying to different slider animation using css clipping effect and don't want to change the way. So sorry for it.

Comment: Ok, if you don't want to change approach, i can give you a little tip, your code is quite working, but is my think, you should use only one variable for currentSlide, you don't need currSlideL and currSLideR, but only currSlide, and check if it's allways more than 0 and less than slides.length before of every slide changes increasing or decreasing it according to left click or right click